# Gnuplot: problems with filling

Tags: fill, gnuplot

Using Gnuplot, I tried to fill the surface between a discrete gaussian and the x-axis: the problem comes when the gaussian is cut from the bounds parallel to the y-axis. 
This is the result:[image: The ugly effect]

The code (splitted in two files):

```
set terminal pngcairo 
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1.2]


########
set border linewidth 1.5
# Axes
set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1
set border 3 back ls 11
set tics nomirror out scale 0.75
# Grid
set style line 12 lc rgb'#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
########

#set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set style function filledcurves below x1=0
set clip two
```

---

```
plot '../results/free' u 1:t w filledcurves below lc rgb "forest-green"  notitle
```

Any suggestion to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any source or tell us what you tried, but:

> The filledcurves style is only relevant to 2-d plotting. Three
>   variants are possible. The first two variants require either a
>   function or two columns of input data, and may be further modified by
>   the options listed below. The first variant, closed, treats the curve
>   itself as a closed polygon. This is the default.
>
> **The second variant is to fill the area between the curve and a given
>   axis**, a horizontal or vertical line, or a point.

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node245.html#5596

"Second variant" means option `{above | below}` (e.g. `plot ... with filledcurves below`)

Comment: The commands:
`set style function filledcurves below x1=0`
`plot '../results/free' u 1:t w filledcurves below lc rgb "forest-green"  notitle`

I added _below_ but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Gabriele: try "set style function filledcurves below x1"

Comment: still not working...

Comment: you need to **remove the** "=0" ( http://plotshare.com/index.ws/plot/139136922 )

Comment: I did so and it isn't working still: the problem isn't with a generic function as you did, but when plotting data, and only at borders.

Comment: same link, but with arbitrary data points ( http://plotshare.com/index.ws/plot/139136922 )